# Как получить столбец матрицы?

Tags: python-3.5

Есть матрица:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Мне нужно получить столбец этой матрицы.
Подскажите, почему `a[:][0]` выдает

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

а не

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

?

Comment: Можно вот так: `x = [x[0] for x in a]`

Comment: borisrozumnuk, спасибо за ответ. Но мне нужно со срезами. И возникает вопрос , почему последовательность a[0][0], a[1][0], a[2][0], ..., a[7][0] выдаст первый столбец, а a[:][0]  - нет? Ведь это одно и то же, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: вроде как `a[:][0]` почти равнозначно `a[0]`. Почти, потому что создается копия `a`.

Comment: @borisrozumnuk, понял теперь. Спасибо.

Comment: Надо умножить матрицу на вектор, в котором все элементы, кроме i-го (номер столбца, который нужно получить) равно нулю, а i-ый равен единице. Результатом такого умножения станет i-й столбец. А студент получит пятёрку за необычное решение с применением  алгебры, вместо тупого перебора элементов массива.

Answer (score 3):

```
a=np.array(a)    
a[:, 0]
```

выдаст первый столбец и тд, надо только задать матрицу явно

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Почему так происходит? Дайте, пожалуйста развернутый ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/149318)

Comment: Не выдаст. Даже 3.6.1 пишет "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Comment: чтобы ошибки не возникало следует задать матрицу явно:   a=np.array(a)